# "Short circuiting" void methods with Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, methods, moq

my team has made the decision recently to use Moq as our mocking framework for its tremendous flexibility and highly readable syntax.  As we're new to it, I'm stumbling on what appears to be simple questions--searches (here, Google, etc.) find plenty of discussions on other nuances of Moq, but not necessarily what I'm after, and the few seemingly related questions have turned into red herrings.

We're testing a class that has an external dependency (Amazon SimpleDb to be precise) but don't want our tests bound to having a live connection out.  A particular method:

- Applies some "business" logic
- If appropriate, invokes a call out to SDB via a provider we've built, let's call it `SaveItem()`

I want to unit test this such that we setup the context required and insure that `SaveItem()` was invoked, but in a manner that `SaveItem()` really isn't invoked (because A) the provider to SDB is a mock that isn't fully hydrated and will likely bomb and B) I don't want to have to pay for that transaction hundreds and thousands of times).

When dealing with methods that returned a value, this was trivial.

```
mockDb.Setup(d => d.GiveMeSomething()).Returns("Foo");
```

In the case that I outline above though, my "`SaveItem()`" method is void and therefore the option to use Moq's `Returns()` method isn't available.  And while I can setup a callback to verify `SaveItem()` is invoked, I can't however seem to get it to not actually do anything.

Naive/hopeful, I thought the following would work, but it appears to still invoke the method:

```
mockDb.Setup(d => d.SaveItem(It.IsAny<object>()));
```

So the million dollar question: What's the Moq of the following fictitious code?

```
mockDb.Setup(d => d.SaveItem(It.IsAny<object>())).STOP_RIGHT_HERE();
```

Comment: Edited to clarify the situation, the test is for a "business" class floating around, not for the actual SimpleDB implementation.  The SimpleDB implementation is tested elsewhere, here, it's what I'm mocking.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If the `SaveItem()` method is virtual or abstract, and you're not setting `Callbase = true`, then the method should be re-implemented to do nothing by the mock.

You should be able to do:

```
mockDb.Setup(d => d.SaveItem(It.IsAny<object>())).Verifiable();

...  test here ...

mockDb.Verify();
```

Comment: Perfect!  Absolutely had no idea that was the intention of the Verifiable() / Verify() stuff, and w/o more formal documentation, wouldn't have even known to read up on threads and posts in that area.

Just gave it a whirl and I've got both positive and negative test cases against this scenario now.  Thanks much!

Comment: +1; In addition, you can also verify all your calls regardless of the Verifiable() flag by calling mockDb.VerifyAll()

Comment: Possible for this answer to be expanded for the other scenario i.e method is neither virtual nor abstract?

Comment: @leon it will work equally with non-abstract. It has to be virtual, though, for Moq to mock it out (it subclasses and overrides)