# Moq Error: Cannot cast 'AnObject' to 'System.Delegate'

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

I have been trying to get past this problem for a couple of days now to no avail. I am trying to test the functionality of AnObject.AnAction (preemptive apologies, I have to obfuscate class/method names.) My goal is to keep MyTestObj.do_work(AnObject) from actually doing anything when it is called. It has code that I do want to be called in a unit test environment.

Here is my Unit test code:

```
Mock< MyTestObj > myTestObj_mock = new Mock< MyTestObj > ();
myTestObj_mock.Setup( e => e.do_work( It.IsAny< AnObject > () ) );
...
AnObject tester = new AnObject();
tester.anAction( myTestObj_mock.Object );
```

within the method AnObject.AnAction( MyTestObj mto ):

```
...
mto.do_work( this );
...
```

It is at this point when ran that I get this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type  
'myNamespace.AnObject' to type 'System.Delegate'.
```

MyTestObj.do_work is a virtual method.

I have absolutely no idea why this error is coming up. I've stepped through the code as NUnit ran it and I am certain that is the point in which it crashes. It will not go any further into  the code.

I'm really stumped. Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

---

****Updates**********

I tried to create an instance of AnObject within AnObject.AnAction and pass it instead of 'this':

```
...
AnObject test = new AnObject();
mto.do_work( test );
...
```

This did not have any effect.

Comment: What is the parameter in do_work(param?)?

Comment: An instance of AnObject.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried to pass in something other than this (new up an AnObject) and ran the test?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I just tried your suggestion but unfortunately it did not change the error message.

Answer (score 3):

As your question is written you do not need to setup the myTestObj_mock.do_work().

Setup is used to say, when method X is called return value Y. Or alternativly that when method X is called, exception Z is returned. Ask yourself is that really what I need to do?

Here you aren't returning anything from the method:

```
mto.do_work( this );
```

Also, here:

```
myTestObj_mock.Setup( e => e.do_work( It.IsAny< AnObject > () ) );
```

You aren't defining any Return for your setup.

You should be able to supply a mock myTestObj_mock without defining the setup in this case. Just remove the line with the Setup and run the test again.

*A guess:*

If you defined the Setup because you wanted your test to make sure AnObject.AnAction really calls the do_work method, what you need to do is define a Verify method rather than a Setup, likewise:

```
mock.Verify(foo => foo.Execute("ping"));
```

or in your case something like

```
myTestObj_mock.Verify(m => m.do_work(It.IsAny< AnObject > ()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

*Another guess:*

If you defined the mock because you pass a "this" reference and expect do_work to modify some parameters of "this" for the test to pass then you shouldn't be mocking here. Remember that mocks aren't really instances of your objects, so the code that modify the this reference will never get called.

Comment: I gave your suggestion a shot without any luck. 

Also, I am not testing the MyTestObj class, but AnObject class. MyTestObj.do_work(AnObject) calls certain networking procedures that will not work in a unit test. I was calling the Setup method in order to dummy up the method so it does nothing. 

I'm sorry, I really should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to get to a compiler and play with the code and here is what I found. It is basically what Giles said above for his first part of the question.

Here is the code hint for Setup:

> Specifies a setup on the mocked type for a call to a value returning method.

And, here is the actual code for Setup

```
public ISetup<T> Setup(Expression<Action<T>> expression)
```

So, Setup is actually setting up the code as an Action (a delegate, basically). When the test runner is run, it hits this point and usually expects to feed the delegate to the Returns method

```
public IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns(TResult value)
```

So, this is never done, and instead of Mock running through the whole expected path and negotiating all of the code out, then it returns mistyped values.

Sooo, this is basically where Giles explanation is correct. If you are testing that the do_work method is being called, then you want to use `Verify` (which truly uses your fake object as a mock). However, if not, then you have no need to even set this up as it does nothing. If that is the case, then maybe that piece of code should not be in that specific code block, but you would be best to evaluate that.

And, finally, the Setup method should only be used if you are truly using your object as a stub, simply using it to inject logic into your code.

Hopefully, that makes sense and helps you with your problem.

Also, a `Callback` might be of use here depending on what you are doing. But, I am not sure. They have many examples in the [Moq quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)

**UPDATE FOR MY ATTEMPT AT RECREATING using Version 4.0.10827...and had no issues**

```
    [Test]
    public void teststuff()
    {
        Mock<MyTestObj> myTestObj_mock = new Mock<MyTestObj>();
        myTestObj_mock.Setup(e => e.do_work(It.IsAny<AnObject>()));
        AnObject tester = new AnObject();
        tester.anAction(myTestObj_mock.Object);
    }
```

...

```
public class MyTestObj
{
    public virtual void do_work(AnObject o)
    {

    }
}

public class AnObject
{
    public void anAction(MyTestObj obj)
    {
        obj.do_work(new AnObject());
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, on top of this, it does look like this kind of already has been asked...sort of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203529/short-circuiting-void-methods-with-moq

Comment: Everything you're saying is making sense. Like the link you shared, I  want do_work to not do anything. I don't really care to make sure it is being called. I removed the Setup line of code and tried to let it run as is but it still kicked back the same error.

Comment: How about just make sure we are on the right path, add .Verifiable(); to the setup and see if it works. You dont have to call Verify I believe. If that doesn't work, (and even if it does), then I would be curious to see if setting up a callback with nothing might even work here. .Callback(()=>{});

Comment: I gave it a shot and it was a no go. Still is complaining how it can't cast. Do you think there is a chance that this is a bug on Moq's part?

Comment: I am beginning to think it is. I only researched, and did not try this myself. I will try something similar myself and see what I get, but that probably wont be until later

Comment: OK, what is the version of Moq that you are using. I just did this on my PC and have no problems.

Comment: I am using Moq.4.0.10827, the most recent version as of last week. I suppose I will have to track down the source and walk through it. Thank you very much for looking it over for me! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I **JUST** tried this using the same version and got no errors. My code is pretty bare bones, but I have posted it in an update at the bottom of my answer. I would try re-installing Moq and see if that helps. If not, can you post your full code as it maybe is doing something else along the way...Or, cant you post it? Otherwise, I cant help with something I cannot reproduce doing the same thing...

Comment: Dang, that is frustrating. I checked the classes and they all are a simple step off from Object. Unfortunately, I cannot post the code but I really appreciate the time you put into this, Justin. Wish me luck finding the problem... I'll need it!

Comment: Good luck. Just a note that might help. Begin removing logic to take it down to the basics and see what happens. Theoretically, when you take it down to the basics like I have it, then it should work...that would at least let you know if it is a problem with your Moq reference or your code